# how to enable flash plugin in phonegap android app?

Tags: android, cordova

i've read some old post, that mention add the following lines

```
    super.init();
    super.appView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

but i use phonegap 2.7, setPluginsEnabled is deprecated. Any solutions?